# Rest Template is not maintaining order

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have two spring based applications. 
Application 1 is the returning list based on sortOrder
Example: `[{"name": "Abc", "sortOrder": 1}, {"name": "Xyz", "sortOrder": 2}]`

This order is maintained while fetching, I validated through Postman rest client.

Application 2, We have restTemplate, which fetches this list from Application 1. The response type we put is List, But I am not getting a list in order manner.
I looked into convertors. But no luck.

Comment: Why don't you sorting after parsing it ?

Comment: I am trying to understand what is changing its order in code.